# Alternating blocks of code with PHP

Tags: php, persistence

I have a form where user puts in a piece of info. Once they submit form it will call my php script that does stuff and spits out info.

The php script makes a webcall and I am trying to set it up so that the code will alternate between one url and the other.

I've tried to use getters and setters to do this but I think the problem lies in that there is no persistant variable so the first block of code is always called.

Is there a way to store a variable in PHP so if I can have the code alternate between different sessions? So if one unique user uses the form it will call the first url and then another unique user or the same one enters another piece of info it will call the alternate url instead.

Comment: What's the intent behind alternating URLs?  are you trying to load balance or something?  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, different approaches might be viable -- for example you could simply pick one of the two URLs at random.  Also, please provide a brief code excerpt demonstrating what you've already tried.

Comment: Save the data to a flat text file or a database. So on the first call you save a txt file with the value 1 in it. On every call, open the file, check the number, call the alternate url, increment or reset the number and save the file

Comment: memcache and APC are both likely candidates for storing variables that need to persist between requests.  Or your database.

Comment: I have two different api keys and I am trying to spread out requests evenly over the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own variables to the SESSION array. This will be "remembered" between page loads.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['MyOwnSessionVariable']))
  $_SESSION['MyOwnSessionVariable'] = "New data";

$MySessionData = $_SESSION['MyOwnSessionVariable'];
```

When you load the page for the first time `$_SESSION['MyOwnSessionVariable']` will not exist. This is how you can know when to initialise.

After each page load the `$_SESSION['MyOwnSessionVariable']` will be "new Data";
The $_SESSION variable is per session, so it is not a problem when you have multiple users at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you could accomplish this, depending upon the exact behaviour desired. If you want a unique user to always see same URL, but different users to see randomly selected URL, just write it to the session.

You could always do a toss (random selection) whether or not you want any session affinity. ALso, if you want strictly alternate selection instead of randomly uniform distribution, you will have to persist the state somehow (DB, file or such).

If you are using APC or Memcache, you could have the same result as persisting the state without the performance penalty.